# SAS Expanders and Hp Smart Array HBA mode

Tags: hp, hp-smart-array, sas, hpe

I've recently purchased an HP DL360p G8 with a Smart Array P420i 1GB storage controller.
As I'm using FreeNas, I've switched the controler to HBA mode.

I was planning to buy an HP SAS expander, this one: 
https://support.hpe.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=emr_na-c01733557
And then buy a couple SAS Backplanes, because from the P420i specs, this controller supports 27 drives.

My question is does the expander work even with the controller in HBA mode?

Thanks.